# hook a functions to change wp-config from functions.php

Tags: functions, wp-config

is there a way to hook / filter or add action that would be printed in the wp-config file? lets say i want to add some simple command like "empty the trash" aka

```
define('EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 1 );
```

This should be changes in the wp-config but i want it to go with theme..

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is, as far as I know, no way to hook into `wp-config.php` from a Theme. For one, `wp-config.php` shouldn't be writeable; for another, `wp-config.php` is executed [well-before a Theme's `functions.php` file is parsed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference). For a great overview of how WordPress boots, have a look at this two-part post by Theme.FM ([part 1](http://theme.fm/2011/09/wordpress-internals-how-wordpress-boots-up-2315/), [part 2](http://theme.fm/2011/09/wordpress-internals-how-wordpress-boots-up-part-2-2437/)) or this [Explanation with a flowchart by @Rarst](http://www.rarst.net/script/wordpress-core-load/).

You might want to look into removing the `define()` from `wp-config.php`, and moving it into the Theme? I'll have to look to see where it gets used, but there's a good chance that WordPress won't have looked for it before `functions.php` gets parsed.

**EDIT**

As per @ChristopherDavis' comment below, `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` gets defined at `wp-settings.php`, via `default-constants.php`. So, you *have* to define it in `wp-config.php`, if you want to override the default.

**p.s. why would you want to define the number of trash days in a *Theme*, anyway?**

Comment: removing the `define` doesn't work.  WordPress sets up defaults if they aren't defined in `wp-config.php` http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/default-constants.php the functions in there get called in `wp-settings.php`

Comment: @ChristopherDavis Well there ya go, then! Thanks for the clarification. (Note, I was referring to *moving* the `define()` to `functions.php`, not to *removing* it entirely.)

Comment: RE: the edit.  Yes, exactly.  It's not really a theme or plugins job to try and change wp-config options.

Comment: ChristopherDavis, kaiser & chipbennett - Thanks a lot for the debate, your answers and the refrence links - it taught a lot :) - I really appreciate it

Comment: Just to expend on the reason i asked - i wanted to create a defaults / custom define attributed after new installation plugin that would offer a lot of easy to set common options. The "empty my trash" option was just a small example

Answer (score 4):

You can just redefine it in your `functions.php` file (call define with the key/value you want).  Since it loads later, it's going to be replaced with your value.  I just tried this with a plugin, it generated some unexpected output errors, but it worked.

That said, if this is a theme for public consumption, it is definitely not your job to change site wide configuration options without consulting your users.  If it's for a client, you should be able to edit their `wp-config` directly.

You're better off to use [xref](http://xref.yoast.com/) (or something like `ack-grep`) to search for where the constant is used and how.  Are there hooks in those functions/whatever that you could used to accomplish the same thing as redefining the variable?

Comment: Couldn't you use `@define( etc... )` to avoid the error output? Not that it's a good idea, but it should work.

Comment: Good call, I suppose you could.  I only saw the "unexpected output" error during plugin activation.  No other PHP warnings/errors (with `WP_DEBUG` set to true).

Comment: Ah, `unexpected output` comes if you want to echo something during activation/deactivation/uninstallation. If you don't do that it's no problem.