# Functions to edit wp-config.php

Tags: options, wp-config

I am writing a plugin in which I have to start by setting it up before using it. This means I may need to update wp-config.php

I know how to edit wp-config.php directly. However the requirement is to also be able to modify it via the plugin settings page. Once the user chooses the correct settings and saves, those settings are updated (added or modified) in wp-config.php

So is there a WordPress method that allows me to find the wp-config file? Is there a WordPress method or API that allows me to update the wp-config.php file? Is there a method that allows me to find and read then edit the wp-config.php entries?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain why you need to edit that file. It really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - The plugin is used for WordPress development only. Only developers will be benefit from it. So, part of the plugin is to enable/disable debugging features. Those parameters are required to be edited via the plugin settings page. I think there isn't any built-in WordPress function that control wp-config.php, and hence I think I will write my own.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with proper server config the wp-config.php file should not be able to be edited from a theme or plugin. It's usually fired first before your plugin/theme files. [Here is a similar discussion on the topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32279/76287).