# How to change constants in WordPress wp-config.php programmatically?

Tags: plugins, functions, wp-config

As the title suggests, I would like to change some constants (in Setting status) in the `wp-config.php` file.

For example `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` I want to set it as. But I want to be able to do this from my own plugin file or from the `functions.php` file in the theme.

**Is there a known solution or rationale for this?**

- In my mind

```php
define('WP_DEBUG', (boolean)get_option('debugging', false));
```

Something like came up, but I haven't tried it yet.

Any kind of help is supported. Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer. This could be helpful - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32277/hook-a-functions-to-change-wp-config-from-functions-php